# phidgets bridge with processing

Tags: processing

I'm using Phidgets Bridge with 3 loads cells, and I'm trying to get the data into processing. For some reason, I keep getting the error: "PhidgetException 5 (Phidget not physically attached.)" Is anyone familiar with it? Thanks!

Thanks for your response. here are some clarifications :) :
The product you've attached is the exact same one I'm using.
To this can be connected 1- 4 load cells, as can be seen here:

http://www.robotshop.com/productinfo.aspx?pc=RB-Phi-118&lang=en-US

The "official languages" according to the Phidgets website, are those you've mentioned, but I'm using Processing, which is Java based language, and I know people do use it with the same device.
The code I'm using is as such:

```
//-----------------------------------------------
import com.phidgets.*;
import com.phidgets.event.*;

BridgePhidget bridge;

float load;
float dataload = 0.0;

void setup(){
size(400,300);
setupBridge();
smooth();
}

void draw(){
readBridge();

void setupBridge() {
try{
bridge = new BridgePhidget();
//bridge.openAny();

bridge.open(140809,"ip_address",5001);
println("Waiting for Phidget");
System.out.println(bridge.getDeviceName());
bridge.waitForAttachment();
println("OK ready to go");
}

catch(Exception e){println("ERROR");
System.out.println(e);}
}

void readBridge()
{
try{

load = (bridge.getBridgeValue(0)); //my load cell is connected to brifge no. 0
}
catch (Exception e){println(e.toString());}
}
```

and the error I get is: "PhidgetException 5 (Phidget not physically attached.)"

I think it is relatively common error, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I followed all the advice I was given.
Hope now it is more clear.
Thanks a lot

---

**Information:**

A Phidget's bridge is a multiple input wheatstone bridge assembled printed circuit board assembly manufactured by "Phidgets".

- The PhidgetBridge lets you connect up to 4 un-amplified Wheatstone bridges, such as:
  strain gauges
  compression load cells
  pressure sensors/Barometers
  piezoresistive accelerometers
  Magnetoresistive sensors (Compasses)
- Product Features
  Interfaces to up to four Wheatstone Bridge based Sensors
  Supports variable data rates – from 1 to 125 samples/second
  Software configurable amplification
  Great interface for Load Cells, Strain Gauges
  Connects directly to a computer's USB Port

[image]

[4 input bridge home page here](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?product_id=1046_0)

[Code here](http://www.phidgets.com/documentation/web/flashdoc/files/phidgets/PhidgetBridge-as.html)

[4 input Phidget's brige manual](http://www.phidgets.com/documentation/Phidgets/1046_0_Product_Manual.pdf)

Comment: You have to elaborate on your question. It doesn't make any sense to me and probably to many others. What is Phidgets Bridge? What is Processing? What is your setup? Pictures? Diagram? Snippets of the source code?

Answer (score -1):

Phidgets Bridge

[**data sheet here**](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?product_id=1046)

[**User guide here**](http://www.phidgets.com/docs/1046_User_Guide)

[Application guides](http://www.phidgets.com/docs/Category:Application_Guides)

Lots of related pages [here](https://www.google.co.nz/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Phidgets+Bridge)

Information section added to your question - please check to ensute that this properly relates to your device.

The product page listed in the information section contains code examples for the languages listed below. Which language are you using? Are you using their code? Please advise web address of code being used.

Please provide connection diagram that you are using.

Language samples for:

```
    AppleScript
    C# (Windows)
    C/C++ (Standard C/C++)
    C/C++ (MS Visual C/C++)
    Cocoa
    Flash AS3
    Flex AS3
    Java
    LabVIEW (64bit; Windows Only)
    LabVIEW (32bit; Windows/Mac OSX/Linux)
    Max/MSP (Windows)
    Max/MSP (Mac OSX)
    Python
    Ruby
    Visual Basic .NET
    Visual Basic 6.0
```

Comment: thanks for your response. here are some clarifications :) :

Comment: (I've updated my original question)

Comment: I'm not sure that mocking someone by posting an answer with just links to documentation is appropriate.

Comment: @PeterJ You should be sure - that would be wholly inappropriate [IMHO, as ever]. **BUT** if you have any experience of how this site works (and with that rep level you should have) then you'll be aware that [**as originally asked**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/2d73de4c-6dd6-41a1-ac9e-01fd959dbb36/view-source)  this question would have been stamped on viciously, closed, shredded, mutilated and spindled.  I added the information that he definitely should have added ....

Comment: .... @PeterJ  [**so it looked like this**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/291c133e-75fb-4af7-a9f7-311a85624909/view-source).  Subsequent edits [**are here**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/37369/revisions) . The OP added versions 3 and OLI added v4. | And there it stopped. The user seemed thankful but did not come back. Total days on site = 3 inclusive. | I tidied it up as a resource 3+ years later. Then no further action until now when you abuse me for my efforts for reasons which are uncertain. Whatever.

Comment: @PeterJ What hat are you wearing?